# Python: Decoding 'Idna' characters does not work correctly with punycode

Tags: python, unicode

My application receives URLs from a Twitter object. The URLs come in Punycode format, such as 'http://xn--espaol-zwa.come'

In my application, I specify the characters as byte and then decode idna type. It works for some URLs, not all the URLs

It works for this URL:

```
>>> url1= 'www.xn--alliancefranaise-npb.nu'
>>> r= url1.encode('utf-8')
>>> r.decode('idna')
'www.alliancefrançaise.nu'
```

Not this one

```
>>> url1= 'http://xn--espaol-zwa.come'
>>> r= url1.encode('utf-8')
>>> r.decode('idna')
'http://xn--espaol-zwa.come'
```

I want a code that work for any URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the accepted answer in and of itself is correct. The Python built-in idna codec is working. I tested it in 3.5.2 and 3.7.0. The real problem is that the example is wrong headed. The idna codec is strictly for DNS hostnames not URLs.

Original example that doesn't work:

```
>>> url1= 'http://xn--espaol-zwa.come'
>>> r= url1.encode('utf-8')
>>> r.decode('idna')
'http://xn--espaol-zwa.come'
```

Original example that doesn't work after removing the URL prefix:

```
>>> url1= 'xn--espaol-zwa.come'
>>> r= url1.encode('utf-8')
>>> r.decode('idna')
'español.come'
```

It is import to remember idna is only for DNS hostnames and it only allows a restricted set of characters. It should not be applied to URLs or entire strings with a hostname embedded in them. There is a built-in Python punycode codec that is even more restricted and only properly handles a punycode encoded string with the xn-- prefix removed. I believe the punycode is the underlying codec used by the idna codec and that the punycode codec is not useable at a higher level without scaffolding code to feed it only the hostname part with a xn-- prefix and and can only decode the part after the xn-- prefix not the xn--hostname-xyz.com full hostname or the xn--hostname-xyz just hostname-xyz.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [specialized module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/idna) for this rather than depending on the `encodings` implementation.

```
>>> import idna
>>> print (idna.decode('xn--espaol-zwa.come'))
español.come
```

The docs for the `idna` module say:

> This acts as a suitable replacement for the “encodings.idna” module
>   that comes with the Python standard library, but only supports the
>   old, deprecated IDNA specification (RFC 3490)